# how to proof (f1+f1 = f2+f2 -> f1 = f2) in coq

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq. I want to proof a lemma:

```
Require Import Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.
Definition fadd (f g:R->R) := fun x => f x + g x.
Notation "f +f g" := (fadd f g) (at level 61, left associativity).
(** f+f = g+g->f=g **)
Lemma fun_add: forall f g, f +f f  = g  +f g  -> f = g.
```

but I dont know how to do it.I have proofed plus comm lemma with ring

```
Lemma fun_add_comm : forall f g, f +f g = g +f f.
Proof.
intros.
apply functional_extensionality.
intros.
unfold fadd.
ring.
Qed.
```

but it seems doesnt work in this.

Comment: The example you give is not self contained, you should add `Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.` as the first line: this will help future readers of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do mathematics in CoQ, I suggest you have a look at the SSReflect tactics language, as well as the Mathematical Components libraries (and book, available [online](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/)).

Here is a proof of your lemma using this framework (there are probably simpler versions).

```
From Coq Require Import Init.Prelude Unicode.Utf8.
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Require Import Reals.
Open Scope R_scope.

Definition fadd (f g:R->R) := fun x => f x + g x.
Notation "f +f g" := (fadd f g) (at level 61, left associativity).

Lemma fun_add: forall f g, f +f f =1 g +f g  -> f =1 g.
Proof.
move=> f g eq2f2g x. 
move: (eq2f2g x).
rewrite /fadd -!double => eq2fx2gx.
by apply: (Rmult_eq_reg_l 2).
Qed.
```

Note that the `=1` equality used here for function equality corresponds to functional extensionality (two functions are equal if their applications to any argument are equal).

Comment: `=1` corresponds to pointwise equality of functions, not to functional extensionality which is an axiom saying `f =1 g -> f = g`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Théo; I was not precise enough..

Answer (score 1):

With the tactics library that you are using comes an automatic proof extension, called `lra`.  YOu can benefit from it.

```
Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.
Require Import Reals Lra.
Definition fadd (f g:R->R) := fun x => f x + g x.
Notation "f +f g" := (fadd f g) (at level 61, left associativity).

Lemma fun_add: forall f g, f +f f  = g  +f g  -> f = g.
Proof.
intros f g adds.
apply functional_extensionality.
intros x.
assert (adds_on_x : (f +f f) x = (g +f g) x).
   rewrite adds.
   reflexivity.
unfold fadd in adds_on_x.
lra.
Qed.
```

It is not easy to recognize
that `f x + f x` is actually `(f +f f) x`, so you need to help the system by making it explicit in the statement of the `assert` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
Require Import Reals Lra.

Notation "f =1 g" := (forall x, f x = g x) (at level 80).
Notation "f +' g" := (fun x => f x + g x)%R (at level 61).

Goal forall (f g : R -> R), f +' f =1 g +' g -> f =1 g.
  intros f g H x.
  pose proof (H x) as Hx.
  lra.
Qed.
```